# Firefox 20 does not open select box

Tags: windows-8, firefox, user-interface

I am using Windows 8 with Firefox 20 and - like seen in older versions - in some cases the select box does not open at all.

The HTML is wrapped by a form, so I do not expect the html to be wrong.
Also, I deactivated all add-ons, to be sure they are not causing the issue.

Any ideas?

UPDATE:
somehow it seems that this happens when the content of the page changes, e.g. i expand a list view above this select box in (own ), that means the position of the select box changed after that it does not react to any interaction anymore

Comment: Is this a site you are developing?

Comment: Yes, please provide the link to your webpage or the source code...

Comment: its an intranet project. the code standard html select code. nothing fancy.